# Why I cannot step into WPF source code in VS?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, debugging, debug-symbols, symbol-server

I'm using VS 2013 with .NET 4.0, and have configured Debug settings as http://referencesource.microsoft.com/. I can step into some core libraries like `List<T>` but still cannot step into WPF code. VS shows "Source Not Available" for WPF components.

Does Microsoft provide the symbols and source code for WPF through its public symbol server?

Comment: disable the option "just my code" in debugger options: https://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC720093.jpeg and also enable .Net source stepping

Comment: @magicandre1981 Already did that. Please note the type in dlls like mscorlib can be stepped in, but WPF dlls can't.

Answer (score 0):

The official source code has been released by Microsoft and [is available on Github](https://github.com/dotnet/wpf).